# Warning: MariaDB version ['8.0', '31'] is less than 10.6 which is not supported by Frappe

Tags: python, mariadb, frappe

I am trying to create a new site bench new-site library.test

```
Warning: MariaDB version ['8.0', '31'] is less than 10.6 which is not supported by Frappe

Installing frappe...
Updating DocTypes for frappe        : [=====                                   ] 12%Syntax error in query:
create sequence if not exists access_log_id_seq nocache nocycle None


There was an issue while migrating the DocType: Access Log
```

my current Mariadb version
**mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.10.2-MariaDB, for osx10.17 (arm64) using  EditLine wrapper**

Comment: [Version 10.10.n of MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-10100-release-notes/) is an active development (alpha) release as of late Dec 2022. Your error message makes it sound like frappe is gacking on the version number 10.10. Maybe try 10.9 or some earlier version? Maybe file a bug or PR with the frappe developers telling them about this?

Comment: @O.Jones 10.10.2 is GA and not an alpha version.

Answer (score 2):

The warning message `MariaDB version ['8.0', '31'] is less than 10.6 which is not supported by Frappe` tells you that Frappe connected to a MySQL Server 8.0.31 and not to MariaDB.

MySQL doesn't support  `CREATE SEQUENCE` and therefore returns a syntax error.

Solution: Stop/uninstall MySQL 8.0.31 and install/start MariaDB.

Comment: I'm getting the same warning and If I do stop MySQL and only have MariaDB running and then create a new site throws the error: `pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)")`
how do I address this?
reference: https://discuss.frappe.io/t/you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds-to-your-mysql-server-version-for-the-right-syntax-to-use-near/92434